# Using WASD and arrow keys simultaneously

Tags: java, keyboard, processing, 2d-games

I am developing a two player game in Processing (running on Java). One user will control his character using the WASD keys and the other will control movement using the arrow keys. The problem I am having is that using `keyPressed` negates WASD when arrows are pressed and vice versa. I have been messing around with it for a really long time. Does anyone know a work around or notice something that I am doing wrong?

```
//global variables
int wide = 600; //canvas width
int tall = 600; //canvas height
int s = 50; //player size
float speed = 2.5; //player movement speed

//colors
int redColor = #CB4646; //player 1 color
int blueColor = #4652CB; //player 2 color
int backgroundColor = #DBE3B3; //background color
float player1X = 600/3-s;  //HOW COME width/3 DOESN'T WORK??????????
float player2X = 600*2/3;
float playerY = 600/2-(s/2);

//players
Player player1 = new Player(player1X, playerY, s, speed, "wasd", redColor); //player 1
Player player2 = new Player(player2X, playerY, s, speed, "arrows", blueColor); //player 2

//setup
void setup(){
  background(backgroundColor);
  size(wide, tall);
  smooth();
  println(player2.controls);
}

//draw
void draw(){
  background(backgroundColor);
  player1.usePlayer();
  player2.usePlayer();
}

class Player{

   //class variables
   float x; // x position
   float y; // y position
   int s; //size
   float speed; //speed
   String controls; //controls
   int colors; //player color
   char keyControls [] = new char [4];

   //construct
   Player(float tempX, float tempY, int tempS , float tempSpeed, String tempControls, int tempColors){
     x = tempX; 
     y = tempY; 
     s = tempS; 
     speed = tempSpeed; 
     controls = tempControls; 
     colors = tempColors; 
   }

   void usePlayer(){

     // draw player
     fill(colors);
     rect(x, y, s, s);

     //move player
     keyPressed();

     //wraparound
     boundaries();

   }

   void keyPressed(){

     //sets controls for wasd
     if(controls == "wasd"){ 
          if(key == 'w' || key == 'W'){ 
            y -= speed; //move forwards
          }
          if(key == 's' || key == 'S'){
            y += speed; //move backwards
          }
            if(key == 'd' || key == 'D'){
            x += speed; //move right
          }
          if(key == 'a' || key == 'A'){
            x -= speed; //move left
          }
         }

      //sets controls for arrows 
      if(controls == "arrows"){ 
        if(key == CODED){
          if(keyCode == UP){ 
            y -= speed; //move forwards
          }
          if(keyCode == DOWN){
            y += speed; //move backwards
          }
            if(keyCode == RIGHT){
            x += speed; //move right
          }
          if(keyCode == LEFT){
            x -= speed; //move left
          }
         }  
        }  
       }

    //pacman style wraparound
    void boundaries(){
     if(x == width) x = 2;
     if(y == height) y = 2;
     if(x == 0) x = width-s;
     if(y == 0) y = height-s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it related to the fact that keyboards can't register more than 2-6 (depending on which ones) keys down at once?

Comment: @Patashu, I dont think so because it doesn't work when I press just two at the same time.

Comment: Note this isn't actually a Java question, but a Processing question. Processing is a very specific API with a slightly different programmign model than Java (it gets rewritten to java for offline use in a JVM, but it gets rewritten to JavaScript when using it online in a browser, for instance)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the info, I didn't know that! I will refrain from posting Processing questions with Java tags in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Track your keys independently, don't rely on the event globals.

```
boolean[] keys = new int[255];

void keyPressed() {
  keys[keyCode] = true;
}

void keyReleased() {
  keys[keyCode] = false;
}

void draw() {
  updatePlayers();
  drawStuff();
}

void updatePlayers() {
  if(keys[LEFT]) { p1.move(-1,0); }
  if(keys[RIGHT]) { p1.move(1,0); }
  if(keys[UP]) { p1.move(0,-1); }
  if(keys[DOWN]) { p1.move(0,1); }

  if(keys['a']) { p2.move(-1,0); }
  if(keys['d']) { p2.move(1,0); }
  if(keys['w']) { p2.move(0,-1); }
  if(keys['s']) { p2.move(0,1); }
}
```

Note this has to be a series of if statements, because you want to handle all pressed keys. If someone's holding left and right, p1 will move left, and right.

Also note that this example code doesn't filter for the higher-than-255 codes you get for special keys, so you probably want to put an "if(keyCode>255) return" at the start of the event handlers.

Comment: Im having a bit of trouble following the logic behind this. I apologize, I am new to Processing and programming in general and I really appreciate your help. Are you suggesting that I remove the usePlayer method and replace it with a move method that receives my `speed` float as a parameter that is incremented on to `x` and `y`? I am just having a bit of an issue visualizing how I would convert this to my `Player` class. Also, I am getting the error message **cannot convert from boolean to int** regarding this code `keys[keyCode] = true;`.

Comment: yes: use some explicit logic for moving your player by some left/right and up/down value, and determine that value based on every key that's currently registered as down. So before you draw your players, your process all the keys that are down for this frame, then you call the player's draw function. Also, the "cannot convert ..." error was because I was silly and accidentally told you to use int[] instead of boolean[] >_>

Comment: Thanks so much the help! I just applied this logic to my program and it moved the arrows keys perfectly. It would register two keys pressed at once and move diagonally! I am however having trouble getting the WASD keys to work though. I think it has something to do with what you suggested regarding the fact that they are `key` not `keyCode` values. What would it look like to get them both to work?

Answer (score 0):

Is `key` a global variable? I don't see it getting passed to the Player. If it's global, then it can only hold one key at a time, which precludes controlling two players at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Arduino/Processing code that I used to handle simultaneous key presses (to move diagonally). It fixes the issue with `boolean[] cannot be cast to int[]` error as shown by @Brannon and uses keyCodes instead of key.

```
import processing.serial.*;
​
boolean[] keys = new boolean[255];
Serial port;
​
void setup() { 
 port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);
​
}
​
void draw() {

  // loop through boolean array and see which ones (index = keyCode)
  // are true, then write to them.
  for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    if(keys[i]) { 
      if (i == 87) { port.write('w'); }
      if (i == 65) { port.write('a'); }
      if (i == 83) { port.write('s'); }
      if (i == 68) { port.write('d'); }
    } 
  }
}
​
void keyPressed() {
  keys[keyCode] = true;
}
​
void keyReleased() {
  keys[keyCode] = false;
}
```